# "Uncaught TypeError: inventories.map is not a function".?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

After deleting an item from the database and updating the UI with hook, I am getting this error saying

```
"Uncaught TypeError: inventories.map is not a function".
```

What could be wrong with my code and How to solve this issue?
Here is the full code:

```
const ManageInventories = () => {
  const [inventories, setInventories] = useInventory()

  const handleDeleteItem = (id) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/manageinventories/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ id })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setInventories(data)
      })
  }
  return (
    <div className="manage-inventories-style">
      <h3 className="pt-3 mb-3">Manage Inventories</h3>
      <Container>
        <Table size="lg" striped bordered hover variant="dark">
          <tbody>
            {inventories.map((inventory) => (
              <InventoryDetails key={inventory._id} inventory={inventory} handleDeleteItem={handleDeleteItem}></InventoryDetails>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
        <div className="mt-3 pb-5">
          <Link className="manage-inventories-btn d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center w-25 mx-auto" to="/additem">
            Add new Item
            <FontAwesomeIcon className="me-2 ms-2" icon={faLongArrowAltRight}></FontAwesomeIcon>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are `inventories` really an array when you're setting here `.then(data => setInventories(data))`?

Comment: If your response is a JSON and you are subsequently passing the data parsed from this JSON to ```setInventories```, I would wager you are setting ```inventories``` to an object and not an array. You should check the type of ```inventories``` using ```console.log(typeof inventories)``` and ensuring it is certainly an array. If not, ensure you extract the array from the ```data``` object using whatever key it is stored under. Also, is ```useInventory()``` a custom hook? Are you sure it's not supposed to be ```useState([])```?

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your stuff is inventories is a promise and render is running before promise resolved

```
{
   inventories && inventories.map(inventory => <InventoryDetails
                                key={inventory._id}
                                inventory={inventory}
                                handleDeleteItem ={handleDeleteItem}
                            ></InventoryDetails>)
}
```

you also csn use if else rendering that will be great although

Comment: ```inventories``` is not a promise; it is updated from within a promise (likely to an object). OP needs to first ensure that ```inventories``` is always an array, otherwise their code will still fail, even with this addition.

Comment: @Ben he is doing setInventories using  fetch call which will take time to get resolve is it not a promise

Comment: ```setInventories``` is triggered from within a promise. ```inventories``` is never itself a promise; it should always be an array (I postulate OP is setting it to an object within the fetch call). If OP were to just use an empty array as the default value for ```inventories```, ```inventories && inventories.map``` would not be unnecessary as the original code would always be valid and the render would simply lag behind by however long the fetch call takes.